# How to search and replace from the last match of a until b?

Tags: regex, vim, latex

I have a latex file in which I want to get rid of the last `\\` before a `\end{quoting}`.

The section of the file I'm working on looks similar to this:

```
\myverse{some text \\
some more text \\}%
%
\myverse{again some text \\
this is my last line \\}%
\footnote{possibly some footnotes here}%
%
\end{quoting}
```

over several hundred lines, covering maybe 50 `quoting` environments.

I tried with `:%s/\\\\}%\(\_.\{-}\)\\end{quoting}/}%\1\\end{quoting}/gc` but unfortunately the `non-greedy` quantifier `\{-}` is still too greedy. 
It catches starting from the second line of my example until the end of the quoting environment, I guess the greedy quantifier would catch up to the last `\end{quoting}` in the file. Is there any possibility of doing this with search and replace, or should I write a macro for this?

EDIT: my expected output would look something like this:

```
this is my last line }%
\footnote{possibly some footnotes here}%
%
\end{quoting}
```

(I should add that I've by now solved the task by writing a small macro, still I'm curious if it could also be done by search and replace.)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you're trying to match from the *last* occurrence of `\\}%` prior to `end{quoting}`, up to the `end{quoting}`, in which case you don't really want *any* character (`\_.`), you want "any character that isn't `\\}%`" (yes I know that's not a single character, but that's basically it).

So, simply (ha!) change your pattern to use `\%(\%(\\\\}%\)\@!\_.\)\{-}` instead of `\_.\{-}`; this means that the pattern cannot contain multiple `\\}%` sequences, thus achieving your aims (as far as I can determine them).

This uses a *negative zero-width look-ahead*  pattern `\@!` to ensure that the next match for *any* character, is limited to not match the specific text we want to avoid (but other than that, anything *else* still matches). See :help /zero-width for more of these.

I.e. your final command would be:

```
:%s/\\\\}%\(\%(\%(\\\\}%\)\@!\_.\)\{-}\)\\end{quoting}/}%\1\\end{quoting}/g
```

(I note your "expected" output does not contain the first few lines for some reason, were they just omitted or was the command supposed to remove them?)

Comment: I think this is a great answer (much better than mine) and should be accepted as a working solution. At the very least, it deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You’re on the right track using the non-greedy *multi*. The Vim help files
state that,

> "{-}" is the same as "*" but uses the shortest match first algorithm.

However, the very next line warns of the issue that you have encountered.

> BUT: A match that starts earlier is preferred over a shorter match: "a{-}b" matches "aaab" in "xaaab".

To the best of my knowledge, your best solution would be to use the macro.